# How many solutions has this third degree equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

how many solutions has this equation:

$$ {x}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}-1=0 $$

i tried ruffini so far and it is not working, now i'm stuck and no idea of how to aproach this.

Comment: What is "ruffini"?

Comment: How many? 3 solutions, did u mean how many real?

Comment: yes, real solutions given im coursing first year calculus

Comment: Wow, third graders are solving cubic polynomials now adays?  I feel out of touch with the younger generation already.

Comment: by ruffini i mean this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule

Comment: You can tell it has 3 real roots because $f(1)$ +ve, $f(0)$ -ve, $f(-1)$ +ve, $f(-4)$ -ve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derivative of $f(x)=x^3+4x^2-1$ is $f\,'(x)=3x^2+8x$, which is $0$ at $x=0$ and at $x=-\frac83$. Since the function is cubic with a positive leading coefficient, it has a local maximum at $x=-\frac83$ and a local minimum at $x=0$. If you calculate $f\left(-\frac83\right)$ and $f(0)$, you should be able to tell very quickly how many real solutions the equation has.

Comment: i wrote the same thing, just not as elegent as yours, as always, a precise answer (+1) :)

Answer (score 3):

The equation has three solutions.

To prove this, look at the values of the right hand side at these values of $x: -4, -1, 0, 1$. The values alternate between positive and negative, so there is a root between each pair of $x$ values I gave you. That gives three solutions, and a cubic can have no more than three solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For a cubic equation $f(x)$ if $f'(x)$ is $0$ at $a$ and $b$.

Then, if $f(a)f(b)<0$ then the equation has three real roots and if $f(a)f(b)>0$ then it has a single real root.

Here $a=0$ and $b=\frac{-8}{3}$

Can u take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x^3 + 4x^2 - 1$.  Then $f(0) = -1$, and $f(1) = 4$, so we know there is a real root $x = r$ in the interval $r \in (0,1)$.  Now divide:  we obtain the factorization $$f(x) = (x-r)(x^2 + (r+4)x + r(r+4)).$$  Now use the quadratic formula on the quadratic term to isolate the remaining roots:  $$x \in \left\{ \frac{-r-4 \pm \sqrt{16-8r-3r^2}}{2} \right\}.$$  Note the discriminant $16-8r-3r^2$ for $r \in (0,1)$ is always positive (it is smallest when $r = 1$), so this quadratic has two distinct real roots, hence $f(x)$ has three real roots.  Now it remains to show whether these roots are distinct.  The two roots of the above quadratic cannot be equal (otherwise the discriminant would be zero), so we must test if $r$ equals either of these two roots.  Setting them equal gives $r = -8/3$ and $r = 0$, respectively, neither of which is true, so we know that $f(x)$ has three distinct real roots.  No calculus, and a minimum of trial and error (noting the change in sign in $(0,1)$ is fairly obvious).